# How to install insync in void linux?

Tags: package-management, google-drive, void-linux

I am trying out void linux in a virtual box.

Is there a way to install insync in void linux? Being an independently developed linux distro, it is not easy to install insync on void linux.

Can someone help?

Comment: I would download the deb for ubuntu and then `ar x` it. That will give you access to a tarball which you can probably extract to somewhere like /opt or /usr/local

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert the deb package to a local package that can be installed in void linux using the script xdeb https://github.com/toluschr/xdeb.

It was easy to convert and install using the xdeb script.